# How to update a single attribute in a Elasticsearch Document

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to update a single attribute in a Elasticsearch Document. This is how we are doing it right now not sure if its perfectly thread safe as we see it fail sometimes

```
Profile profile = profileRepository.findById(id);
profile.setStatus(status);
profileRepository.save(profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Spring Data Elasticsearch is already doing that for you. You can check that by enabling the logging on Spring Data Elasticsearch and check what is being sent to Elasticsearch. Generally speaking Spring Data keeps track of the changes you make on a session object.

Another way to do it is to make use of the `@Query` annotation (the code is not tested/verified)

```
@Query("update Profile set Profile.status = :status)
void updateProfile(String status);
```

In case that is not working you can use the Update API from Java REST High Level Client https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update.html